# replace two or more numbers with one char in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

what i want to do is using this code

> asking for an input

```
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
charFF = "55"
```

> replacing every "55" with "A" - not to replace "5"

```
for i in charFF:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, "A")
print(orgtxt)
```

but this code replaces all the 5's not only "55"

> if user input was 10530855 it will replace all the 5's with A and the output will be 10A308AA, but i need it to be 105308A

Comment: This works `'10530855'.replace('55', 'A')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
    orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
    charFF = "55"
    print(orgtxt.replace(charFF, 'A'))
```

Comment: it works but when i have more than one char to replace it doesn't work, means when i have charRR ="66" and doing the same code it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are iterating over your charFF variable character by character.
So in the for loop, the variable i is '5' at its first iteration and then again '5' in the second.

Just hold on to the direct replace() like pointed to by the other ansers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Encoding files required for text files
The problem you replace a int with string , You need to replace strgin with string ..

```
orgtxt = str(input("Enter text: "))
//For file or list
//orgtxt = open("file.txt","r",econding="Latin-1").read()

charFF = str("55")
print(orgtxt.replace(charFF, "A"))
```